# Unable to display special characters in IE

Tags: php, html, joomla

I'm working on a site that has a basic search function to search through products with ajax and display the results along with what was searched for. However, for reasons beyond my understanding, if the search contains any special character `(ie. é, è, ê)`, the character is replaced with a box. I can't figure out where exactly things are going wrong, and why this is only affecting IE.

The code:

```
<div class="aux_title"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->search_term); ?></div>
```

[The site](http://asp.geantduweb.ca/documents-audiovisuels) operates using joomla if that helps/changes anything.

Comment: Typical charset problem, but it can be anywhere in the process that your data is not properly encoded/decoded. As this only happens in IE8, I would presume only this browser is using a wrong charset, probably wrongly auto-detected, or forced.

Comment: @Bartdude I checked the charset being used with `mb_detect_encoding` and it claims to be `UTF-8` encoded. Such special characters appear on the page in other areas just fine, only the search results seem to be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your charset to UTF-8

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Or another charset that better supports your languages. 
[Charsets](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ref_charactersets.asp)

Comment: Just tried, no visual change. The bizarre part of the problem is that it only occurs in IE, every other browser I've tested with display the characters appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an adequate solution to my peculiar problem.

```
<?php
    $enc = mb_detect_encoding($this->search_term, mb_detect_order(), true);

    if ($enc != 'UTF-8') {
        $this->search_term = utf8_encode($this->search_term);
    }
?>
<div class="aux_title"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->search_term); ?></div>
```